# Converter method getAsObject() getAsString() never called

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters, selectcheckboxmenu

The convert doesn't work.
This is the code abount my xhtml(For now I need to list only all values):

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="autoriRicerca"
                        value="#{ricercaLibroBean.autoriRicerca}" 
                        converter="autoriConverter"
                        multiple="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                        panelStyle="width:250px">
```

This is my Converter:

```
@FacesConverter("autoriConverter")
public class AutoriCoverter implements Converter {
    @Inject
    private AutoriDAO userService;

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {

         if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            try {
                return userService.getListaAutori();//return the lis about  authors
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("%s is not a valid User ID", submittedValue)), e);
            }

    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return "";
        }
        if (object instanceof Autori) {
            Autori autore = (Autori) object;
            String nomeAutore = autore.getNomeAutore();
            return nomeAutore;
        } else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(object + " is not a valid car"));
        }
    } 
}
```

in my bean I have:

```
private List<Autori> autoriRicerca; // and get and set method
```

the class `Autori` has a `(id,nameAuthor).`

I don't know which is the problem. It seems like the code doesn't enter in the converter method. I have put some breackpoints and they doesn't execute in debug. Anyone an help me?

Comment: Sure the xhtml is deployed? What if you make a typo in the `converter="...."`?

Comment: @Kukeltje you mean if  I don't specufy anything in the converter?

Comment: No specify something that is completely bogus and see if you get an error then

Comment: and please make a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

In the `public Object getAsObject` of the FacesConverter you have to return a single Object given the submitted id, not the complete list.

In the `public String getAsString` you have to return the object id given the object.

For example

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {

     if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return userService.getAutoreByID(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));//return the author by id
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("%s is not a valid User ID", submittedValue)), e);
        }

}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return "";
    }
    if (object instanceof Autori) {
        Autori autore = (Autori) object;
        Long autoreID = autore.getID();
        return autoreID;
    } else {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(object + " is not a valid user"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not answering the real problem at all. *"Converter method getAsObject() getAsString() never called"*, *"it seems like the code doesn't enter in the converter method"*, *"I have put some breackpoints and they doesn't execute in debug"*.